# trying to derive from a dijit Button: "TypeError: this._attachEvents is undefined"

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to derive an "extended" Button from dijit/Form/Button. (I want to pass extra arguments to the constructor, and I want to encapsulate these preparations in my derived class. Button is just an example, I want to use this later with grids and trees.)

Unfortunately the code below fails with "TypeError: this._attachEvents is undefined" in the firefox javascript console. Some idea, what is wrong? The same code, including minimal HTML, is ready to run at http://jsfiddle.net/x9dLs8gz/1/

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/json", "dojo/domReady!"],

function (declare, Button, dom, json) {
    declare("MyButton", Button, {
        "-chains-": {
            constructor: "manual"
        },
        constructor: function () {
            //extra calculation will go here...
            this.inherited(arguments);
        }
    });
    new MyButton({
        label: "Click Me!",
        onClick: function () {
            dom.byId("result").innerHTML += "Success";
        }
    }, "button").startup();
});
```

Cheers,
Dominic

Answer (score 1):

If the `"-chains-"` value for the `constructor` method is either not set or set to `"after"`, then the `postscript` method will be called after all of the inherited `constructor`s have been fired. On the other hand, when specifying `"manual"`, `postscript` is fired after the first `constructor` (in this case `MyButton#constructor`) is executed. As a result, `_AttachMixins#buildRendering` is fired before `this._attachEvents` has been set in `_AttachMixins#constructor`, causing the error you see.

Since specifying `"manual"` means that no chaining is assumed whatsoever, mixin contructors will *never* be called, even if `this.inherited` is correctly called up the chain. This makes sense, as the underlying [C3MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) is thrown out the window.

If you need to continue using the `"manual"` setting in spite of this, you will need to 1) recreate any missing data yourself, 2) manually call the mixin constructors (e.g., `_AttachMixin.prototype.constructor.call(this)`), or 3) convert `MyButton` to a factory for `Button`:

```
var createButton = (function () {
    var myButtonDefaults = { ... };

    return function (kwArgs, id) {
        var buttonId = id || 'button';
        return new Button(lang.mixin({}, myButtonDefaults, kwArgs), buttonId);
    };
})();

var myButton = createButton();
myButton.startup();
console.log(myButton instanceof Button); // true
```

Comment: As an aside, you only need to specify the class name when the declared class will be used by the Dojo parser. If that is not the case, then it is better to assign the value returned by `declare` to a variable and omit the name from the call to `declare`: `var MyButton = declare(Button, {});`.

Comment: As explained at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html#calling-superclass-methods, "Superclass constructors are always called automatically, and always before the subclass constructor. [...] If it doesn’t fit your needs see Manual Constructor Chaining below." Because I want to construct additional arguments to the Button constructor inside the MyButton constructor, I think I do need the "manual" "-chains-". Probably this example is oversimplified to make the point clear.

Comment: I have asked for help on a slightly more complicated example here: http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2015-May/084353.html Maybe this example clarifies better, how I want to encapsulate constructor arguments in my derived dijit.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Given that, I updated my answer above, since what you are trying to do is not possible when mixins are involved.

Comment: Thank you for your updates. However, with my limited knowledge I cannot make it work. Both, calling the mixin constructor or using your factory suggestion still result in the same "TypeError: this._attachEvents is undefined" (in firefox console). You find an example ready to run including constructors for both options at http://jsfiddle.net/x9dLs8gz/5/ . Would you be able to make it run without errors?

Comment: Apologies; I misremembered returning a new object from `constructor` behaving like returning a new object from a native constructor. So the (yet again) updated answer demonstrates a correct way of handling this, and you can see a demo at this updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0o558h41/1/

Comment: Thank you, I have been using this factory pattern as a workaround until now. However, I was looking for a solution to create a derived dijit class (not only an object), where I have the chance to initialize some properties prior to calling the base class constructor, in the style of c++ initializers: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html . I can't believe this is impossible in javascript. How about you second suggestion to call the _AttachMixin constructors manually - my unsuccessful attempt is included in the commented code at jsfiddle.net/x9dLs8gz/5?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the declared class to a variable or declare in a different file and added it to the list of object in the require. Also dont use variable names which are keywords like "constructor". below is the fixed version of your example.

```js
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/json", "dojo/domReady!"],

  function(declare, Button, dom, json) {
    var MyButton = declare("MyButton", Button, {
      "-chains-": {
        constructorType: "manual"
      },
      constructor: function() {
        //extra calculation will go here...
        this.inherited(arguments);
      }
    });
    new MyButton({
      label: "Click Me!",
      onClick: function() {
        dom.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Success";
      }
    }, "button").startup();
  });
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you change the required keyword "constructor" inside "-chains-" to "constructorType". Afaik constructor chaining is supposed to be written as I did. Your code doesn't invoke my modified constructor BEFORE the original Button constructor as intended, but AFTERWARDS.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question properly. As mentioned in your comments earlier. the manual constructor is dependent on calling this.inherited(arguments). Your class will call the button call constructor, but the constructor of the classes that the button extends will not be called hence, what you trying cannot be achieved. by using constructor. Try to use PostCreate or PostPropertiesMixin etc method to achieve your goals instead.